# SQL Query & Optimization: With multiple searches in various columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and I want to search all of these numbered columns for one specific value AND with name = Bob

So:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND 1="value" OR 2="value" OR 3="value"
```

and so on..

What would be the most efficient and best way of doing this? And in the instance that the columns are actually numbered like in my example, is there a way to index inside the query to just loop from 1-10?

Thank you.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 ... are awful names for your columns. At the very least, it is error prone as `1="value"` is valid (syntactically), but does not probably do what you expect: it merely compare the value `3` with the string `"value"` -- producing a result *always* false. You probably want to write `\`1\`="value"`...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `OR` use `Union`.

Something like this:-

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND 1="value"
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND 2="value"
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND 3="value"
```

Comment: I fully agree with you. But in this case it would be better to use Union instead of OR. Check this out:- http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/union-or-sql-server-queries/

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f649/1 ! results are not the same thats why you should avoid union if you need dublicates.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the most efficient and best way of doing this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND `1`="value" OR `2`="value" OR `3`="value"
```

My bet is the above statement using `OR` is probably one of your best choices.

There are (probably) several other variations. Anyway, you will have to compare them using [`EXPLAIN SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see if it perform better or worst -- depending on *your* particular data and indexes.

Just to conclude this "answer", here is one alternative solution. At the very least, more readable than a bunch or `OR`...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = BOB AND "value" IN (`1`,`2`,`3`)
```

---

BTW, as I said in a comment above, `1`, `2`, `3` ... are *not* good columns names. I won't repeat myself here, but here an transcription that shows *why* it is error prone, and what's going on when you write `1 = "hello"`:

```
mysql> SELECT True FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = "hello";
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'hello' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT True FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = "hello";
+----+-------------+-----+------------------+
| id | select_type | ... | Extra            |
+----+-------------+-----+------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ... | Impossible WHERE |
+----+-------------+-----+------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```